# Error (internetKeychainItemForServer:withUsername:path:port:protocol:) - The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: git, macos, keychain, atlassian-sourcetree

I get the following error while I try to push my code to github using Sourcetree:

```
Pushing to http://github.myOrg.com/my-repo/my-proj.git
2014-09-23 13:05:20.500 git-credential-sourcetree[6744:507] Error (internetKeychainItemForServer:withUsername:path:port:protocol:) - The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
remote: Permission to ion-my-repo/my-proj.git denied to my-user-id.
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.myOrg.com/my-repo/my-proj.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

When I hit push, sourcetree asks me for my password related to my account:

```
Password required
For user my-user-id on host github.myOrg.com
```

So it looks like sourcetree knows what is my user id and it just needs the password to access my github account. I am able to pull the contents using sourcetree and it doesn't ask me for my credentials. I was also able to do push to this project, but recently my system admin did something on my mac with keychains and since then I am not able to push anything on github.

Did anyone came across this issue before?

Comment: I manually added the credentials to keychain and this seems to work.

Comment: Could you tell us how ?

Comment: In keychain : add 'bitbucket.org' entry in 'Passwords' category.

Comment: i think your access on this project removed by admin

Comment: @tech_human Hi, I had the same issue as you. I put a bounty on your question. jfcartier's answer solved the issue for me. Have you tried his solution yet?

Answer (score 16):

I was having the exact same issue. It seems that `ssh` agent somehow lost my credentials. I realized it when I attempted to list all my ssh keys using the `terminal`:

```
$ ssh-add -l
> The agent has no identities.
```

So I ran

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_rsa_key
```

I entered the password for my key. And the issue went away.

So, I don't know exactly why or how my ssh agent lost its keys all of a sudden but if that is the same problem you are having, you can solve by adding the ssh key back using `ssh-add` command.

This might be one of those issues that have many different causes and solutions, I am just proposing a solution for my case.

Comment: That worked for me! What is weird is that if I open `Keychain access` and search for `ssh` I can see the key there. It was actually the ssh-agent that didn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error because of the "two-factor authentication". 
Once you use the "two-factor authentication" you have to creat a personal access token, and you should enter it instead of your password when performing Git operations over HTTPS.
[Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)